# Robust weighted random string generator

Tags: python

I have implemented the following class to generate either 'p' or 'q' based on a input frequency of 'p'. However, this implementation breaks if the frequency gets smaller than the size of the list used to store the options. Is there a way in which I can implement this to work for any value of p?

```
from random import random

class AlleleGenerator(object):
    """
    allele generator - will break if p < 0.001
    """
    def __init__(self, p):
        """construct class and creates list to select from"""
        self.values = list()
        for i in xrange(int(1000*p)):
            self.values.append('p')
        while len(self.values) <= 1000:
            self.values.append('q')
    def next(self):
        """Returns p or q based on allele frequency"""
        rnd = int(random() * 1000)
        return self.values[rnd]
    def __call__(self):
        return self.next()
```

Comment: Required reading, in case you need to adapt to more than two possible values: Bendersky's article on [weighted random generation](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/) in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `self.values`. In `next`, just generate a random number between 0 and 1, and return `'p'` if the random number is less than `p`:

```
from random import random

class AlleleGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, p):
        """construct class and creates list to select from"""
        self.p = p
    def next(self):
        """Returns p or q based on allele frequency"""            
        return 'p' if random() < self.p else 'q'
    def __call__(self):
        return self.next()
```

Also, be careful [not to use classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0#t=9m26s) when a function suffices.
For example, you might consider using a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
from random import random

def allele_generator(p):
    while True:
        yield 'p' if random() < p else 'q'

agen = allele_generator(0.001)
for i in range(3):
    print(next(agen))
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use `random.uniform()` to ensure a uniform distribution.  I don't think `random.random()` yields a sequence of values that is distributed evenly enough to make this algorithm statistically accurate.

Comment: @SilasRay: [random.uniform](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0056aaf42bf7/Lib/random.py#l340) calls `random.random`. `random.uniform` is useful for generating random numbers in an arbitrary range `[a, b)`. For the range `[0, 1)`, use `random.random`.

Comment: Hmm, true... Looking in the code, I see they use Wichman-Hill, which from Googling, looks to reliably produce a good uniform distribution.  I stand corrected.  :)

Comment: [Changed in version 2.3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html): MersenneTwister replaced Wichmann-Hill as the default generator. (Also: "Note that this Wichmann-Hill generator can no longer be recommended: its period is too short by contemporary standards, and the sequence generated is known to fail some stringent randomness tests".)

Comment: Ahh, your right, didn't pay close enough attention.  That's implemented in `_random.Random`.  Only thing I'd say then is it might be worth it to bind each generator to it's own `random.Random` instance, depending upon how much fidelity you need.